# How can I do a table in Java (Netbeans)?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I've been trying to draw a table using netbeans, but I haven't had any result, what I'm trying to do is, if the space in the array is empty i need to put the number of the position, i mean, 0 is 1, and 1 is 2..etc. If the space in the array has a value in there i need to put something like this "x", the table must be like this:

[image]

how could I start?

Comment: We would need to have more information about the code, what is the data you want to print? ArrayList? 2D array? Give us more details and we will be able to help you for sure (Danos más detalles y seguro que podremos ayudarte :) )

Comment: Ok, sorry, i´m blind, i now see you wrote it is an array, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much information, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
for(int arrayNumber=0;arrayNumber<NUMBER_OF_ARRAYS;arrayNumber++){

        for(int i=0;i<array[arrayNumber].length;i++){

                System.out.print(array[arrayNumber][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
}
```

Where:

1. arrayNumber is the current row,
2. NUMBER_OF_ARRAYS is the total amount
3. i is the column.